# How to extend Alfresco Share existing activity list dashlet with my own activity type?

Tags: share, alfresco

In Community 4.0.a, I'm posting my custom activities in the repo following this: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.0_Activities_Developer_Guide

I have defined my own activity type, with custom bundles and pagelink to display custom needs in the activity dashlet.
But I face an issue, I need to specialize the output based on the activity-type in a similar way of what is done already in activity-list.get.js in the specialize() function.

I can't hack the js cause I'm packaging things in my own amp for Share.

What is the best way to do it? Is there some kind of extension point or do I need to override completely the dashlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way (3.x) to change the behaviour of a webscript controller is to copy the code and overwrite the Javascript by placing it under **web-extension**: `alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/activity-list.get.js`. There you can modify the specialize() function or whatever you need to do.

All files you place in the `alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts` folder will replace original files in the share.war `WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts` classpath. Best practice is to place your customizations in the `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension` folder so you don't need to modify the WAR file.

Alfresco 4.0 provides a new way to change the javascript controllers of a webscript. You can add additional Javascript code that will run after the original code. This is preferable because you don't need to change original code and you can upgrade more easily later. To use it you need to get familiar with the new Share extension modules concept. See [David Draper's Blog](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/ddraper/2011/08/05/customizing-alfresco-share-javascript-controllers/) for more info on that.